# Print in python chose the arg like in c

Tags: python, printing

I am looking for something similar in python print in printf c.
Is there something like that in python ? `printf("%2$c %1$c", a, b).`

Comment: you want `str.format`: `"{1} {0}".format(a,b)` right?

Comment: `print('%s %s' % (b, a))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.format` is designed to repeat arguments or change their order when passing a position (starting at `0`):

```
a = 10
b = 20
print("{1} {0}".format(a,b))
```

you get:

```
20 10
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, the `%` operator lets you select elements from a `dict`, although the `format` method is still the better way to go.

```
>>> print("%(two)s %(one)s" % {'one': 1, 'two': 2})
2 1
>>> print("%(one)s %(two)s" % {'one': 1, 'two': 2})
1 2
```